# Piecemeal restore of database with filstream filegroups

Tags: filestream, filegroup

I have tried taking the backup of database containing filestream and it works fine. I have tried restoring it on other server also and that works too.

Now, i am facing a problem. Our database is big in size (approx. 320 GB) and it takes time to backup and restore it. Therefore, the client wants us to suggest some technique to reduce the time.

I have tried piecemeal restore which allows you to backup and restore individual filegroups in the database. It works fine with all the other filegroups except for Filestream ones. I am able to take backup and not able to restore it.

Do u have any idea??

Regards,

Prashant.

Comment: This is a supported scenario and should work. Please provide the commands you're using and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned was solved by changing the recovery model of the database to Full and then taking backups and restoring them with Recovery attribute.

Thanks,
Prashant.